# python3 command in terminal giving No such file or Directory error

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, posix

when i type python3, i get the following error:

python3: posix_spawn: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.72.7: No such file or directory.

I have been using python 3 for years, but today I downloaded homebrew and then this error started popping up!

Comment: Did you try to remove homebrew? And if it didn't work did you try to reinstall python3?